# Question on the derivative of the spherical mean

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

The spherical mean of $u$ is defined as
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{S^2} u(\vec x + r \, \vec y) d\sigma(\vec y).
\end{align}
Now this might be a dumb question, but I don't see how a $r$ derivative, $\partial r$, acts on this. In the literature it says that (if $u$ suff. regular)
\begin{align}
\partial_r \int_{S^2} u(\vec x + r \, \vec y) d\sigma(\vec y) = \int_{S^2} \vec\nabla_x u(\vec x + r \, \vec y) \cdot \vec y \;d\sigma(\vec y).
\end{align}
but why does the multivariable chain rule only produce a gradient for $\vec x$ instead of
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial u}{\partial(x ^i + r \, y^i)} \underbrace{\frac{\partial(x^i + r \, y 
 ^i)}{\partial r}}_{= y ^i}.
 \end{align}

Does it have to do with the fact that all this happens under the integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the important thing is that the spherical mean is a function of $\vec x$ (and $r$), and $\vec y$ is the dummy variable of integration. The choice of notation $\nabla_{\vec x}$ is just emphasizing that if you differentiate with respect to $r$, the resulting expression is still a function of $\vec x$ (and $r$). I think many authors would not even include the $\vec x$ in the gradient, and instead simply write
$$
\partial_r \int_{S^2} u(x+ry)\,d\sigma(y) = \int_{S^2}\nabla u(x+ry)\cdot y\,d\sigma(y).
$$
The intermediate step is
$$
\int_{S^2}\partial_r\big(u(x+ry)\big)\,d\sigma(y).
$$
To evaluate, set $z(r) = x+ry$. By the multivariable chain rule,
$$
\partial_r\big(u(z(r))\big) = \nabla u(z(r))\cdot z'(r) = \nabla u(x+ry)\cdot y.
$$
Or with the dummy index notation,
$$
\partial_r\big(u(z(r))\big) = \sum_i\frac{\partial u}{\partial z_i}(z(r))\frac{dz_i}{dr}(r).
$$
In this notation, $z_i$ is just a dummy variable.

Comment: So what I have in my last line is what is actually happening and the $\nabla_x$ is just a convenient way of writing this?

Comment: @Moeman: I think the notation in your last line was a little imprecise, but essentially yes.

Comment: Okay. I am not sure how this is compatible to what I find in "Sogge's NLW": http://prntscr.com/1wjk8yi . There, if I am not mistaken, $\nabla_x $ is really just $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} $ and not $\frac{\partial}{\partial (x^i+ r y ^i)}$.

Comment: @Moeman: Right, it really is just $\partial/\partial x^i$. In other words, it is just an application of the multivariable chain rule with one independent variable (namely $r$), like on this webpage: https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/14%3A_Differentiation_of_Functions_of_Several_Variables/14.5%3A_The_Chain_Rule_for_Multivariable_Functions

Comment: Okay, I guess I was overthinking all of this. It makes more sense to me now, thanks!